# how to find values of best_in_place checkbox dynamically without refresing the page in ruby injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

This is the code i'm using to get value of the checkbox & set the flag accordingly,

:checkbox, :collection => ["No, thanks", "Yes, of course!"] %>

```
<% if (post.content == "true") %>
    <%= @flag=1 %>

<%else %>
    <%= @flag=0 %>
```

But i'm not getting the new value of the checkbox (value changes by clicking on it) without refreshing a page

Answer (score 1):

The changing check box is client-side... the server (rails and your erb template) knows nothing of it changing. You will probably want to use a client-side technology like javascript to watch for the change and manage the behavior you are looking for.  I would likely use jQuery to do this -- I'd help with the jQuery, but I'm a little unsure of what you are up to. Hope this helps.